# Inconsistent recognition of ranges (No errors thrown)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

This is code from Excel 2010. All of the code resides within the workbook itself. Information is gathered using internal forms and the code is run.

I have code that retrieves data from a spreadsheet and populates an object with that data. The row number is dynamic as it is dependent on the form input. The column is by the header, not the column number. The following code works perfectly but for two anomalies:

```
        cTank.RowForTankSpecs = rNum
        cTank.MP = .Cells(rNum, Range("MP").Column).Value
        cTank.Form = .Cells(rNum, Range("formName").Column).Value
        cTank.TankProcess = .Cells(rNum, Range("Process").Column).Value
        cTank.Location = .Cells(rNum, Range("Location").Column).Value
        cTank.TankName = .Cells(rNum, Range("Tanks").Column).Value
        cTank.tankID = .Cells(rNum, Range("TankID").Column).Value
```

First:

The `cTank.TankName` is retrieving information from a column named "Tanks". That column does not exist. The actual column header is "Tank". But, it is retrieving the correct information. If I change the name to what it really is (Tank), it does not work.

Second:

When the `cTank.TankID` line is executed, I get the following error on the `Range("TankID")`:

`Runtime Error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed`

This one has the appropriate header (column header), but it is not recognizing the range.

I have tried simple things such as changing the order of the code, but it doesn't help. As earlier stated, the other lines work. Later in the program, information is gathered in the same manner but using another worksheet from the same workbook, and none of them are working. I've double checked that strings are strings and integers are integers, etc. I've double checked the column headers match the range names. Nothing seems to jump out at me.

I would appreciate any input you may have on the situation.

Thanks in advance.

Steve

Comment: Where are your **With** and **End With** statements??

Comment: You should qualify the `Range` statements as you do the `.Cells`, e.g., `cTank.TankName = .Cells(rNum, .Range("Tanks").Column).Value`, by adding a period before "Range".

Comment: Hey Doug, the statements are there, they just aren't relevant so I didn't want to clutter it up. They are all within the same spreadsheet and the other lines work fine. For some reason it is just not recognizing any of my other column names and it is misreading the one column name. Maybe added the columns later and for some reason Excel in not seeing them. Oh, putting the dot in front of "Range" just gives me a different 1004 error.

Comment: Ok, I just tried something. I just highlighted each of the columns individually in the spreadsheet. When I highlighted the ones that were being recognized, the column header also appeared in the as the name of the column on the upper left of the spreadsheet. When I highlighted the ones that were not being recognized, the header location came up, i.e. A1 or B1, etc. In other words, it's not recognizing the header titles in some of my columns.

Comment: So I guess the question becomes how do I get Excel to recognize all of my column headers as column headers?

Comment: Aha!! Got it. (Two days later.) It was in how Excel created the spreadsheets. I'll post the solution tomorrow as I am new and can't answer my own question for 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Being pretty sure my code was correct, I went to the spreadsheet itself. For some reason it was recognizing only certain columns and it was recognizing one of them incorrectly. So I started highlighting the columns that worked and also the columns that didn't. What I noticed was that on the columns that were being recognized, that column header was displayed where the cell location is normally displayed whereas on the columns that were not being recognized, the cell location (i.e. A1, A2, etc.) for the header was being displayed and not the header title itself. The incorrect label was showing up for one of them. As it turns out, the mislabeled column was one that I had used for a form dropdown menu. So, I checked the name manager, and the ones that were working were listed. So anyway, using the name manager, I added named ranges using the headers. Now, when I select the columns, the column header(named range) appears in that window and now, the code works.

Thanks guys for your input. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can do:

Do not use use `Range`, but as it seems you are using names, use `Names("Yourname").Referstorange`.

*OR*

Make sure your names are set up correctly using the `Name Manager` in Data Ribbon.

Comment: Thanks.  It was the one that was reading incorrectly that brought me to the Name Manager. Once all of the columns were named, the original code worked like a charm. I may try the "Names("yourName").Referstorange" next time just for diversity. Thanks for chiming in.